# Send an email using mailto function (HTML)

Tags: android, html, email

I am using Android hybrid app, in which one link is used to send email:

`<a href="mailto:shrikantjadhav86@gmail.com" >some text</a>`

Can anyone please tell which permission is required to set to open email client?

This same is working when i open web page in the browser.

Comment: Please read what I have written : `<a href="mailto:` instead of `<a href-"mailto:`

Comment: Do not use `-` you have to use `=`

Comment: @Ty221 I did typo here but the link is correct in actual page and it is working when i open it in browser

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this link is in `WebView`.

If I am true you don't need any permission. Android will open that link in default application automatically.

Comment: You are right, I have added internet permission but when i click on the link it show me 404 page not found screen

Comment: @user1259350 You're link is generally bad, it should be : `<a href="mailto:shrikantjadhav86@gmail.com">Link Text</a>`

Answer (score 0):

android will automatically open email client installed in your device

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add any permission for mailto,

Comment: I have added that permission but when i click on the link it show me 404 page not found screen

Comment: @user1259350 some other error is issued, but for mailto, no required any permission added

Comment: This same is working when i am opening it in the normal browser

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />` in your `config.xml`.